# Log writing in Storage account from Azure Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage

I have a .net code that executes every day deployed in one of the server. Once the code is executed the logs are written in a text file present in the server. I need to migrate the code running in the server to Azure function app. Is there anyway to write the logs once the code is executed into any format file in storage account?

Comment: Do you need every run has a new log file or all of them together in a log file?

Answer (score 0):

In your function app you can go to "Diagnostic Settings" and redirect all logs to a provider of your choice.

[image: Add a diagnostic setting]

[image]

Refer to this for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring&tabs=CMD